Troubleshoot Bicep
I need some help troubleshooting a bicep deployment.  In this case, it's to deploy a sql server failover group but I have similar problems with other bicep.
I see that I have an error on line 24, column 9. How can I see what the values are at this location?
I am using a resource ID on that line (but not that column). How can I tell if it even has a value?
The resource ID comes from an existing resource above. Is there are wat to see the value of the databaseName param that was passed in?
Here is the error:

Unable to process template language expressions for resource
'/subscriptions/ed8e3234-8fcc-4ef0-8438-c12548480e56/resourceGroups/rg-MyProj/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sql-001/failoverGroups/fg-sql-001'
at line '24' and column '9'. 'The language expression property array
index '1' is out of bounds.' (Code:InvalidTemplate)

And here is my bicep:
01: param failoverGroupName string
02: param primarySqlServerName string
03: param secondarySqlServerName string
04: param databaseName string
05: param secondaryResourceGroup string
06: 
07: resource primary 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-08-01-preview' existing = {
08:   name:  primarySqlServerName
09: }
10: 
11: resource secondary 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-08-01-preview' existing = {
12:   name:  secondarySqlServerName
13:   scope: resourceGroup(secondaryResourceGroup)
14: }
15: 
16: resource db 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2022-08-01-preview' existing = {
17:   name: databaseName
18: }
19: 
20: resource sqlServerFailoverGroup 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/failoverGroups@2023-05-01-preview' = {
21:   name: failoverGroupName
22:   parent: primary
23:   properties: {
24:     databases: array(db.id)
25:     readWriteEndpoint: {
26:       failoverPolicy: 'Automatic'
27:       failoverWithDataLossGracePeriodMinutes: 60
28:     }
29:     readOnlyEndpoint: {
30:       failoverPolicy: 'Enabled'
31:     }
32:     partnerServers: [
33:       {
34:         id: secondary.id
35:       }
36:     ]
37:   }
38: }
39: 



Unable to process template language expressions for resource 'The language expression property array index '1' is out of bounds.' (Code:InvalidTemplate):

To define databases property, you need to Use resourceId function to reference the database existed under a specific SQL server as shown below.
databases: [
      resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases', primarySqlServerName,databaseName)
     ]

Complete bicep code:
param failoverGroupName string = 'latestfover'
param primarySqlServerName string = 'jahser'
param secondarySqlServerName string = 'secondserverj'
param databaseName string = 'newdb'
param secondaryResourceGroup string = 'v-jahnavi-Mindtree'
resource primary 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-08-01-preview' existing = {
   name:  primarySqlServerName
 }
resource secondary 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-08-01-preview' existing = {
   name:  secondarySqlServerName
   scope: resourceGroup(secondaryResourceGroup)
 }
 resource db 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2022-08-01-preview' existing = {
   name: databaseName
 }

resource sqlServerFailoverGroup 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/failoverGroups@2023-05-01-preview' = {
   name: failoverGroupName
   parent: primary
   properties: {
     databases: [
      resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases', primarySqlServerName,databaseName)
     ]
     readWriteEndpoint: {
       failoverPolicy: 'Automatic'
      failoverWithDataLossGracePeriodMinutes: 60
     }
     readOnlyEndpoint: {
       failoverPolicy: 'Enabled'
    }
     partnerServers: [
      {
        id: secondary.id
      }
     ]
   }
 }

Deployment succeeded:



Thanks. I saw those examples and I started off that way. I was always getting errors and eventually I abandoned it. I just tried it again and it worked.  I must have had a variable wrong.
This response saved me. I'll mark it as the answer, but technically it didn't answer my quesiton about troubleshooting and seeing the variable values. Still, it's a great help so I will mark it as the answer.
